# What does the custom attribute in healthMonitoring rules do?

Tags: asp.net, health-monitoring

The MSDN doc http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fe5wyxa0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx indicates that there is a "custom" attribute available when adding a rule. But I don't see how it gets used. I can successfully add a custom provider without using it, and all the samples I've seen for adding custom events don't use it either. What does it do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It evaluates whether an event should be sent to the related provider for processing. So you might want to use the custom attribute to do more complex evaluations for checking if the event should be sent to the providers. Check out IWebEventCustomEvaluator http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.management.iwebeventcustomevaluator.aspx  for a specific example and more info.

Answer (score 1):

See the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.rulesettings.custom%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which says that:

> Gets or sets the fully qualified type of a custom class that implements IWebEventCustomEvaluator.

As an example:

```
ruleSetting.Custom = "MyEvaluators.MyCustomeEvaluator2, MyCustom.dll"
```